# Eating after Kiddush Friday Night without Motzi?

Tags: meal-seudah, kiddush, leil-shabbat, mezonot-beracha

In many synagogues, it is common to have an informal food gathering after services on Shabbat morning. This is very rarely, if ever, done Friday night. On Shabbat morning the way it's done is usually to have one person make Kiddush for everyone, and then everyone eats, although generally there is no Motzi made and no bread served. Some are careful to eat Mezonot so that the Kiddush has a Makom Seudah status. There are instances when this is done, along the same lines, at home.

Can one eat after Kiddush *Friday night* along the same lines? If not, why is it different?

Comment: [Sydenham shul](http://www.sydshul.co.za/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=71&Itemid=98) in Johannesburg, South Africa does this. It has become a popular event.

Answer (score 6):

The rules of eating a meal in the same place one made or heard *kidush* are written among the rules of Friday night's *kidush* (and applied to both). Thus, the rule ([*Mishna B'rura* 273:25](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14171&pgnum=107)) that cake suffices for this (so one need not immediately eat bread) applies to the nighttime as well as the daytime *kidush*. (However, even if he is famished during the day and cannot eat cake or the like so eats fruit, he can't do so at night: cake or the like is required at night. *MB* 273:26.)

Why, then, don't people do this in synagogues? I suspect it's practical considerations: women aren't there (in many synagogues, and, in any event, traditionally haven't been there, and old habits die hard), so it's unusual to make a celebration in the synagogue, for the community, Friday night. Moreover, people with children want to go home before the children need to go to sleep. And similar considerations.

Moreover, there are two specific reasons to have a *kidush* with no bread in the morning that don't apply at night. One is that (in many synagogues) the prayers end before lunchtime in the morning, and people want to eat something light. The second is a specific custom ([*Taame Haminhagim*, asterisked footnote to 299](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14556&pgnum=153)) to eat "four meals" (the second of which requires no bread) on *Shabas*, so that some people deliberately (even at home) eat something light and take a break before lunch even if it is already lunchtime.

Comment: 1. What is the reason given by the M"B? 2. What is the source for the 4th meal custom?

Comment: @SethJ Which MB are you referring to?

Comment: @doubleaa Cake being required at night. I can look it up, a but a brief explanation would make for a better answer.

Comment: @SethJ You mean as opposed to fruit? He's quoting the Chaye Adam 2:6:22 who quotes the Elya Rabba which as far as I can tell doesn't exist. It's probably just a chumra because night time kiddush is deoraita.

Comment: @SethJ, re night vs. day, _MB_ doesn't give a reason, and, while I haven't checked, I'll take DoubleAA's word for what he wrote above. Re the fourth meal, see _Taame Haminhagim_, asterisked footnote to 299.

Comment: A third reason to complement your last paragraph, is that prayers often end before chatzot, but close enough that lunch may not start till after chatzot (particularly when not on daylight savings time), in which case people want to eat something so they aren't fasting.

Answer (score 3):

Although [msh210's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17926/14850) would appear to reflect the opinion of Mishnah Berurah which does not differentiate between *kiddush* at night or during the day, there are opinions that argue and would limit the permission to follow *kiddush* with cake instead of bread to only the daytime *kiddush* (at least ideally).

[R. Shlomo Ganzfried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Ganzfried), [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 77:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.77.14?lang=bi):

> וְאִם לֹא אָכַל מִיָּד לְאַחַר הַקִּדּוּשׁ, לֹא יָצָא יְדֵי קִדּוּשׁ. **וּבַיּוֹם** אַף שֶׁאֵינוֹ רוֹצֶה לֶאֱכוֹל מִיָּד סְעוּדָּה קְבוּעָה, יָכוֹל לְקַדֵּשׁ וְלֶאֱכוֹל קְצָת פַּת כִּיסָנִין, וְאָז צָרִיךְ לִשְׁתּוֹת מִן הַכּוֹס רְבִיעִית.‏
>
> And if one did not eat immediately after *kiddush*, he did not fulfill the *mitzvah* of *kiddush*. **By day**, even if he does not want to eat a formal meal immediately, he can recite the *kiddush*, and eat some cake, but then he must drink a *revi'it* [of wine] from the cup.

[R. Yitzchak Elchanan Spektor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzchak_Elchanan_Spektor), [Ein Yitzchak 12:11](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1303&st=&pgnum=39):

> לכתחלה יחוש להחמיר לאכול תיכף לחם אחר הקידוש של לילה אכן בקידוש היום יש להקל ולסמוך על מיני תרגימא או כוס יין שני
>
> Ideally, one should be concerned for the stringent opinion and eat bread immediately following the nighttime *kiddush*. However, at the daytime *kiddush*, one can be lenient and rely on *mezonot* or a second cup of wine.

The reasoning behind this approach is summarized nicely in [this article](https://ohr.edu/6206):

> Although the *Magen Avraham* did not distinguish between the Friday Night and Shabbos Day *Kiddush*, and held that his ruling [i.e. that *mezonot* suffices for the meal following *kiddush* - JoelK] should apply equally, on the other hand, Rav Yitzchok Elchanan Spektor, the Kovno Rav and *Gadol Hador* of the late 1800s, did. He explained that on Shabbos Day, when *Kiddush* is only mandated *derabbanan*, one may certainly rely on *Mezonos* as a *Seudah*. Yet, on Friday night, when *Kiddush* is an actual *chiyuv d’oraysa*, due to the strength of the opposition to the *Magen Avraham*’s approach, he maintains that one should not rely on mere *Mezonos*, but should ensure that *Kiddush* is recited along with an entire bread-based *Seudah*.
>
> This is why one does not often see a Friday night *Kiddush* being performed with *Mezonos* instead of *Hamotzi*.

Comment: IIUC R Soloveitchik (or R Moshe Feinstein?) concurred, reasoning that the Raavad (?) anyway permitted snacks before the morning Kiddush, so there's be a Sefek Sefeka in favor of eating Mezonot after Kiddush then.

Comment: @DoubleAA Raavad (Hil. Shabbos 29:10) maintains there is no prohibition against eating before kiddush with regard to the daytime kiddush. Indeed R. Soloveitchik explained that one may therefore only rely on פת הבא בכיסנין for the daytime kiddush (contra Magen Avraham). See Nefesh HaRav, p. 165